# How to iterator over a nested hash in reactjs with ruby on rails?

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I am converting my code into reactjs written in my ruby on rails app.My backend is based on mongoDB.I has documents which contains hash inside another.I can get the values from key from the outer most hash.But I cannot get the values in the innermost hash.
Sample mongodb documents in my app:

```
    [
       {"_id":20,
        "employment":{"urban":1,"suburban":46,"rural":8},
        "forestarea":{"tropical":53,"subtropical":43,"mediterranean":57,"temperate":75},
        "literacyrate":{"men":64,"woman":92,"others":33},
        "mentowoman":{"urban":21,"suburban":52,"rural":67},
        "name":"Telangana"},
       {"_id":21,
        "employment":{"urban":1,"suburban":82,"rural":86},
        "forestarea":{"tropical":47,"subtropical":78,"mediterranean":42,"temperate":21},
        "literacyrate":{"men":63,"woman":63,"others":9},
        "mentowoman":{"urban":76,"suburban":9,"rural":88},"name":"Manipur"},{"_id":22,"employment":{"urban":10,"suburban":34,"rural":70},"forestarea":{"tropical":60,"subtropical":85,"mediterranean":89,"temperate":59},
        "literacyrate":{"men":0,"woman":43,"others":62},
        "mentowoman":{"urban":22,"suburban":19,"rural":63},
        "name":"Meghalaya"},
       {"_id":23,
        "employment":{"urban":38,"suburban":46,"rural":0},
        "forestarea":{"tropical":25,"subtropical":25,"mediterranean":16,"temperate":81},
        "literacyrate":{"men":89,"woman":1,"others":22},
        "mentowoman":{"urban":35,"suburban":13,"rural":72},"name":"Mizoram"}
    ]
```

Example:
I want to show everything inside the nested hash.My output should look like this in plane `HTML`:(example for one entry)

```
<div>
<h1>Telangana</h1>
<h1>ForestArea</h1>
<ul>
    <li>tropical<p>53</p></li>
    <li>subtropical<p>43</p></li>
    <li>mediterranean<p>57</p></li>
    <li>temperate<p>75</p></li>
</ul>
<h1>Employment</h1>
<ul>
    <li>urban<p>1</p></li>
    <li>suburban<p>46</p></li>
    <li>rural<p>8</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My reactjs code is as follows.Using the below code i can get the values from the hash.But,cannot get the values from hash inside the hash.That is i want key and values from nested hash.

### ReactJs Code

```
var iScroll = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
        console.log("Inside");
    },
    render:function(){
        var states = this.state.states.map(function(item){
            return(<li>{item}</li>);
        });
        return(
            <div>
            <h5>Inside</h5>
            <ul>{states}</ul>
            </div>
            );
    }
});

var ScrollsIndex = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {states:this.props.initialStates};
    },
    render: function(){
        var eachState = this.state.states.map(function(item){
            return(<iScroll states={item}/>);
        });
        return(<div>
            {eachState}
        </div>);
    }
});
```

I want the `key` and `value` from the nested hash as well.
I know how to get values from nested hash in `ruby`.Please guide me in `reactjs`.

Answer (score 0):

Not `react.js` specific, but to iterate over keys if an object in `javascript`, you can use the `keys()` method of `Object`

You also need to pass the whole object to your `iScroll` class, you're only giving the name property and thus don't have access to all the others.

```
return (<iScroll item={item}/>);
```

Something like this for the render method of ScrollIndex:

```
var data = Object.keys(this.props.item).map(function (prop) {
  if (prop === 'name') { return; }
  return (
    <li>{prop}<p>{this.props.item[prop]}</p></li>
  );
});

return <div>{data}</div>;
```

I would advice to refactor a bit the architecture of your hash if you can thought, having different types of data mixed together is not a good practice in most of the cases. Here the name and the multiple props you want to show.

And you don't need to use the state when you got props

Comment: Using your method i can get the key name.but i cannot retrieve the values for the key by using `{this.props.item[prop]}`.

Comment: So you have the full hash when debugging this.props.item?

Comment: Yes under `this.props.item`.i has full hash.

Comment: Do you got an error or just nothing? If you try to access this.props.item.name, this should work for example. Are you sure this is a Json object and not a string?

Comment: from the code i specified in the problem.I got the value for `name` key if i replace `<iScroll states={item}/>` with `<li>{item.name}</li>`.But now i can only see the key names in the outer most hash.

Comment: It's strange to have access to key names but not values, it should be both or none. Doing this.state.state is also not really comprehensible. And why are you setting the `states` property in your initial state but after using the `state` one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96986/discussion-between-ashr81-and-apercu).